# Is this possible to set the language in tinymce editor in javascript?

Tags: tinymce, google-translate

I have using tinymce text edit for my asp.net applications.Now i have added language pack.now i want to set the language pack for the text editor programatically.And also hide the language pack bar from the visible state.

[image]

for example : i want to programatically  set the language of the text editior is hindi.Pleasr guide me to get out of this...

whenever user clicks translation Button in my web form , i have initialized this string variable.then i want to set the tinymce editor language programatically.

string lang="Hindi";

**ptp.js**

```
function LoadTypePad()
{
    // Initialize pad

    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",
        plugins : "safari,style,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,paste,fullscreen,indicime,aksharspellchecker",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontsizeselect,fontselect,aksharspellchecker,indicime, indicimehelp",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "selectall,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,media,advhr,|,print",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        spellchecker_rpc_url:"http://service.vishalon.net/spellchecker.aspx",
        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",
        width : "100%",
        init_instance_callback : "afterInit"
    });
}

function showPleaseWait()
{
    var mainMessage = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = pleaseWait;
    pleaseWait = mainMessage;
}

// This function finds absolute position of the element in screen and returns array.
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return [curleft,curtop];
    }
}
// id= outer most id for show/hide. baseid = reference id for pointer
function showPopup(id, baseid)
{
    toggle_menu(id);
    var base = document.getElementById(baseid);
    var l = findPos(base);
    var obj = document.getElementById(id + 'content');
    var im = document.getElementById(id + 'img');
    var left = im.src.indexOf('left.gif') > 0;

    obj.style.top = (l[1] - obj.offsetHeight - 20) + "px";
    obj.style.left = (l[0] + (base.offsetWidth/2) - (left?obj.offsetWidth:0)) + "px";

    l = findPos(obj);
    im.style.top = (l[1] + obj.offsetHeight - 1) + "px";
    im.style.left = (l[0] + (left?obj.offsetWidth - 26:0)) + "px";
}

function closePopup()
{
    // hide popup
    var elem = document.getElementById("step1");
    elem.style.display = "none";
    elem = document.getElementById("step2");
    elem.style.display = "none";
    elem = document.getElementById("step3");
    elem.style.display = "none";
}
// Once tinymce is fully loaded
function afterInit()
{
    // Find search string from referral
    var term = document.referrer;
    var re = /bengali|gujarati|gujrati|hindi|marathi|devnagari|devanagari|punjabi|gurmukhi|kannada|malayalam|tamil|telugu|thelugu|thamil/gi ; 
    var m = re.exec(term);
    var result ='';
    if (m != null && m.length > 0)
        result = "<strong>" + m[0] + "</strong>";
    else
        result = "your favourite Indic Script";
    // Create popup
    CreatePopup("step1", "Step 1", "Click here to erase existing contents", "right");
    CreatePopup("step2", "Step 2", "Select " + result + " from this dropdown list and start typing.", "left");
    CreatePopup("step3", "Step 3", "Click here to get a help for typing once you selected script in Step 2", "right");

    // Restore the message from please wait to spell checker
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Now Akshar Spell Checker for Gujarati is available!!! Click on <img src=\"tiny_mce/plugins/aksharspellchecker/img/aksharspellchecker.gif\"> to check Gujarati spelling";

    // Initialize for google search
    pph = new PramukhPhoneticHandler();
    pph.convertToIndicIME("q");
    pph.onScriptChange("q", indicChange);

    // Open up popups
    showPopup("step1","elm1_newdocument");
    showPopup("step2","elm1_indicime");
    showPopup("step3","elm1_indicimehelp");

    // Close popup after xx seconds.
    setTimeout("closePopup();",15000);
}

function toggle_menu(id)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.style.display = elem.style.display=="none"? "":"none";
}

function CheckNewVersion()
{
    var JSONRequest = tinymce.util.JSONRequest;
    try {
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
    } catch (e) {
// do nothing
    }
    JSONRequest.sendRPC({
            url : "http://service.vishalon.net/pramukhtypepadmessage.aspx?v=2.5.00",
            method : "",
            params : "",
            type: "GET",
            success : function(r){
                var message = r.substring(r.indexOf(",")+1);
                if (message != "")
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<img src='img/info.jpg' >" + message + "<br><br>";
                },
                error : function(e, x) {
                    // do nothing 
                }
            });
}
function indicChange(id, lang)
{
    var s = document.getElementById('language');
    s.value = lang;
    if (lang == null || lang == "")
        lang = 'english';
    pph.setScript(id, lang);
}
function CreatePopup(id, title,content, dir)
{
    var holder = document.getElementById("plholder");
    holder.innerHTML += "<div id='" +id + "' style='display:none;'>"+
        "<div class='popupbody' id='" +id + "content'>" +
    "<div style='float:right;'><img src='img/close.gif' style='cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;' onclick='toggle_menu(\"" + id + "\");'/></div>"+
    "<div><strong>" + title + "</strong></div>"+
    "<div style='clear:both'></div>"+
    "<div>" + content + "</div>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<img src='img/" + dir + ".gif' id='" + id + "img' style='position:absolute;'/>"+
    "</div>";
}

var pph, pleaseWait = "Please wait while Pramukh Type Pad is loading... <img src='img/progress.gif' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;(Loading problem??? Get <a href=\"pramukhlibex.htm\">Simple Pramukh Type Pad</a> )";
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @ leftyX: sorry  i did not find any solution for that...

Comment: if you want to put your code somewhere I can try and help.

Comment: @LeftyX : Please see my updated question.i have posted my ptp.js file content

Comment: Have you got any HTML as well? Where did you get the plugins from?

Comment: @LeftyX: from http://www.vishalon.net/PramukhIME/Windows.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to download your [language pack](http://www.tinymce.com/i18n/index.php?ctrl=lang&act=download) and unzip it.
Then you have to put every single js file in the corresponding folder of your tinymce folder.
You have to specify the [language](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3alanguage) as well.
If you're using [TinyMCE - jQuery Plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/jQuery_Plugin) you have to do something like this:

```
// Initializes all textareas with the tinymce class
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
      script_url : '../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
      theme : "advanced",
      language: "hi",
      ...
   });
});
```

If you want to remove tinyMCE (and I guess you have to do it if you want to reset the language) from your text-area you can use this code:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'mycontrol_id');
```

as specified [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Command_identifiers).

and you can recreate it using the same code. 
You can wrap everything in a function and pass the language parameter:

```
function setup(language) {
   tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      language: language,
      plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
      theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
      theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
      theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
      theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
      theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
      theme_advanced_resizing : true
   });
}
```

If you want to remove [buttons](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_buttons_1_n) from the toolbar you have to work on these lines:

```
theme_advanced_buttons1 
theme_advanced_buttons2
...
```

removing those you don't need.
There's a list of all buttons and plugins [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Buttons/controls).
If you want to add your own buttons you can find a sample [here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_toolbar_button.php).

**UPDATE**:

Since you've used your own plugin, I guess you have defined it in the plugin section:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    language: 'hi',
    plugins : "myPlugin, pagebreak ... ",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "myPlugin",
    ...
    });
```

If you don't want to show it, just remove it from the **theme_advanced_buttons2**.

Comment: 1. I have downloaded indian languages pack.Now, i have one combo box that contains the indian languages.So, Whenever user select any indian languages then i want to set the selected language as the tinymce editor language. 2. i have my own combo box in my page for selecting language i don't need language bar option in tincymce editor.So, i want to hide it. So,Could you please guide me to get out of this both issues?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Thanks for your answer: I don't want to hide entire tinymce from my editor.I want to hide only the language selection combo box in tinymce.

Comment: @Saravanan: you aretalking about which combo box? (is it a box of your CMS?)

Comment: @Actually,i have added one plug in for indian languages for my tinymce.so, tinymce added one combox for listing indian languages.Please see the attached picture[red rounded circle].i want to hide that combo box.

Comment: @Saravanan : Is this combo-box something you have created (custom button)?

Comment: @Saravanan: I don't understand why you've created one plugin that you don't want to show.

Comment: @LeftyX : Ok thanks i understood.Now my problem is i have separately created one combo box(select button) in html.and then i added all indian languages in it.Whenever user click this combo box for selecting any one indian language, then i want to get the name of the indian language and set it to language of the tinymce editor.Suppose, user selected any other language then i want to set the appropriate language for tinymce editor...

Comment: @Saravanan: that's why I suggested to wrap the creation of your tinyMCE in a function where you can pass the language. You have to destroy it before and the recreate it. Read my answer carefully.You'll find everything there. I've tried it and it works.