# Setting language for TinyMCE 3.x

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE and wanting to display it in Spanish (es)

The TinyMCE version info is as follows

`majorVersion : '3',
minorVersion : '3.9.2',
releaseDate : '2010-09-29'`

The documentation says to download the language pack [from here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Language) and copy the files to the appropriate 
folders:

```
/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/langs/
/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/
/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/<pluginname>/langs/
```

and also set

```
    tinyMCE.init({

        // General options
        language: 'es',
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        relative_urls : false,
        file_browser_callback : ekmUpload,
        plugins: "safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager,filemanager",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,save,print,|,code,preview,fullscreen,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "image,template,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,|,bullist,numlist,|,sub,sup,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,|,hr,removeformat,",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: false,

        content_css : " ",
        editor_selector: "HTMLEditor",
        height : '500',
        width : '100%',
        convert_urls : false,

        inline_styles : true,

        save_enablewhendirty: true,
        save_onsavecallback: "SaveDocuments",
```

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929006/is-this-possible-to-set-the-language-in-tinymce-editor-in-javascript) also gives the same advice.

But the language pack (zip file) only contains `lang/es.js`

Having does this, nothing appears in Spanish, the "format", "font-family" and "font-size" drop downs don't appear in Spanish.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

What you donwloaded is the language file for tinymce 4, you need the language pack for tinymce 3. You will get it here: http://www.tinymce.com/i18n3x/index.php?ctrl=lang&act=download&pr_id=1

Comment: Sorry, I had set the ```language : "es", ``` I just copied and pasted incorrectly into the question. I've updated the question now. Any other ideas?

Comment: what you donwloaded is the language file for tinymce 4, you need the set for tinymce 3. You will get it here: http://www.tinymce.com/i18n3x/index.php?ctrl=lang&act=download&pr_id=1

Comment: I've downloaded the files you suggested. After applying them the TinyMCE editor now adds ```"advanced."``` in front of all items in the drop downs (font family, font size etc). Still doesn't display anything in Spanish.  I've also updated the question again to show my full TinyMCE config. Any more help would be appreciated.

Comment: hmm, can you make a live example available?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in version 3.5.6. The es.js files are all in the right places, but the button mouseover text displays the variable name, not the value for some buttons. Test page [here](http://www.reventsoftware.com/test/test1.html#tabs-1)

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:language

example...

tinymce.init({
    ...
    language: "sv_SE"
    ...
});

You have: language: 'es',